# android : Physical keyboard language switch and mouse clicks do not work in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, dialog, keyboard, android-hardware-keyboard

Physical keyboard language switch and mouse clicks do not work in EditText.

I have created EditText dynamically as shown below.

```
    EditText box = new EditText(this);
    box.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //String message = box.getText().toString();
            //nativeVirtualKeyboardChanged(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
    //box.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    box.setFocusable(true);
    box.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    box.setCursorVisible(true);
    box.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

However, when used with AlertDialog, it works normally. I do not know the cause.

Comment: Mouse clicks on an Android device ? (touch events ?)

Comment: It is a bluetooth mouse click.